# DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION not working

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using

```
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION
```

to indicate what part of a procedure is currently being executed. For example:

```
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION(ACTION_NAME=>'1/9 CALCULATING SPACE AVAILABLE...');
```

Just adding these lines at various points in the stored procedure makes entries in v$session that can be easily queried for information purposes and relayed back to users. However, if I run the same procedure from an oracle scheduler job, I don't get an entry in v$session for the ACTION_NAME. Only details for the job itself are present.

Does anyone know how I might get around this, to produce the same status indicators that are shown when I just execute the procedure manually, instead of by a job?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you initialize the info with `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE`?

Comment: I have this in my procedure DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE('PDU','Starting...');
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION(ACTION_NAME=>'1/9 RUNNING VALIDATIONS...'); and still I see nothing in v$session...

Answer (score 0):

You may add `Dbms_Session.Set_Identifier` besides might be good option to populate the info been derived from v$session dynamic performance view as :

```
Declare
  i_action varchar2(1000):='1/9 CALCULATING SPACE AVAILABLE...';
Begin
  If ( i_action is not null ) Then
    Dbms_Application_Info.Set_Action( i_action );
    Dbms_Session.Set_Identifier( i_action );      
   End If;
End;
```

Comment: I have this in my procedure DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE('PDU','Starting...');
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION(ACTION_NAME=>'1/9 RUNNING VALIDATIONS...'); and still I see nothing in v$session...

Comment: @Scouse_Bob I already suggested using `Dbms_Session.Set_Identifier( '1/9 CALCULATING SPACE AVAILABLE...' )`, too. Haven't you tried ?

Comment: Yeah thanks, I did try - still no entries in v$session